# Can't retrieve data with XMLHttpRequest in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

script.js:

```
 var oReq_a = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq_a.open("get", "test.php", true);
    oReq_a.send();

  function test(){
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = function() {
        alert(this.responseText);
    };
    oReq.open("get", "test.php", true);
    oReq.send();

    alert("(1)"+oReq.responseText+"(2)");
    alert("(3)"+oReq_a.responseText+"(4)");
  }
```

test.php:

```
<?php
  echo "New text";
 ?>
```

I call it in HTML with a

```
<button onclick="test()" value="button"></button>
```

My output is, obviously, **two** alert boxes with

```
(1)(2)
```

and

```
(3)(4)
```

What is the problem? Thanks.

P.S. I'm running WAMP server 3.0.0, PHP version 7.0.

Edit: using network console, opened with F12, (Thanks @EduardVoid) I get this error:

script.js:3 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/wamp64/www/project3_phplogin/test.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Edit2: I tried testing the page in Mozilla and it works, so problem is Chrome related. Any ideas?

Edit3: Tried changing the url to "./test.php". No improvement.

Comment: can you see the request to test.php in network console? if not the problem is in relative URL

Comment: you should get response in onload event.they are asynchronous functions

Comment: @EduardVoid what do you mean by network console?

Comment: @FastSnail I should yes, but I'm not. Or is my code incorrect?

Comment: @Zvone yes incorrect.use onload event.put alert inside onload function

Comment: @FastSnail There is an alert in oReq.onload=function()

Comment: you should get 3 alert boxes.so your http request has failed.you can use error methods to catch it.also network tab is useful to see the request.https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/13274/nm-headers-annotated.png

Comment: press F12 and then find a tab named network :)

Comment: @EduardVoid I edited my question. Any ideas how to fix this now?

Comment: Treating asynchronous calls like they are synchronous. You are ordering a pizza and trying to eat the pizza as soon as you hang up the phone.

Comment: @epascarello okay, but then I would get 3 alert boxes, and I don't get the alert box which is in onload function. Problem seems to be Chrome related (Edit1 and 2). Something about my Request not passing

Comment: Why are you loading php files over the file protocol? "file:///C:/wamp64/www/project3_phplogin/test.php." seems like you are not running it on a local server.

Comment: cross origin error occurs sometimes when the caller's domain is other than the result's. try to edit URL to ./test.php.

Comment: @epascarello Interesting question which I don't really completely understand. I just set this server up and for a few weeks this way of getting php data worked good, and now it doesn't. How do I fix the thing you're refering to in your question?

Comment: @EduardVoid I did, no improvement. :(

Comment: Also, I don't know why this happening: while testing in Mozilla, first alert box I get is the one from onload function, and it's content is: <?php echo "New text"; ?> instead of just New text.

Comment: Sounds like you are not accessing the file from the server, but directly from the file system..